# ASP.NET Web API Contract Versioning

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, versioning

We would like to achieve version based API using content negotiation in accept header.

We are able to achieve for controller & API methods with some inheritance and extending the default HTTP selector.

Controller inheritance is achieved using following sample code,

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseController : ApiController
{
    // common methods for all api
}

public abstract class AbstractStudentController : AbstractBaseController
{
    // common methods for Student related API'sample

    public abstract Post(Student student);
    public abstract Patch(Student student);
}

public class StudentV1Controller : AbstractStudentController
{
    public override Post([FromBody]Student student) // student should be instance of StudentV1 from JSON
    {
        // To Do: Insert V1 Student
    }

    public override Patch([FromBody]Student student) // student should be instance of StudentV1 from JSON
    {
        // To Do: Patch V1 Student
    }
}

public class StudentV2Controller : AbstractStudentController
{
    // 
    public override Post([FromBody]Student student) // student should be instance of StudentV2 from JSON
    {
        // To Do: Insert V2 Student
    }
}

public abstract class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class StudentV1 : Student
{   
}

public class StudentV2 : Student
{   
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

We have created above architecture to do less code with change in version, say if version 1 has 10 API methods and there is a change in one API method than it should be available in version 2 code without modifying other 9(they are inherited from version 1).

Now, the main problem we are facing is in contract versioning as we cannot instantiate an instance of an abstract student. When someone is posting JSON to API version 1 instance of StudentV1 should be passed in methods and same in version 2.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Looks like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306305/binding-abstract-action-parameters-in-webapi

Comment: Thanks @DanielStackenland!!

We don't have any common field like productType to identify the posted JSON.

Also, we will have around 50 - 70 such classes like student in API which will be versioned later when required.

Comment: What is the purpose of AbstractStudentController anyway? Why dont you just let the StudentV1Controller (and V2) inherit the  AbstractBaseController and use StudentV1 (and V2) as parameter?

Comment: @DanielStackenland- AbstractStudentController is to declare the contract of API for all the version.

We cannot use StudentV1 & StudentV2 as cannot use inheritance in a controller contracts. The main purpose is like if we have 10 API methods in version 1 and if only required contract change for one API method then only need to override it in version 2 controller other 9 will be inherited for version 2.

Data contract should be deserialized based on a respective version for that API.

We can attribute to API for the concrete class if required but not in param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ASP.NET API Versioning](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning) is capable of achieving your goals. First, you'll want to add a reference to the [ASP.NET Web API API Versioning](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning) NuGet package.

You would then configure your application something like:

```cs
public class WebApiConfig
{
   public static void Configure(HttpConfiguration config)
   {
       config.AddApiVersioning(
          options => options.ApiVersionReader = new MediaTypeApiVersionReader());
   }
}
```

Your controllers *might* look something like:

```cs
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    namespace V1
    {
        [ApiVersion("1.0")]
        [RoutePrefix("student")]
        public class StudentController : ApiController
        {
            [Route("{id}", Name = "GetStudent")]
            public IHttpActionResult Get(int id) =>
                Ok(new Student() { Id = id });

            [Route]
            public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] Student student)
            {
                student.Id = 42;
                var location = Link("GetStudent", new { id = student.Id });
                return Created(location, student);
            }

            [Route("{id}")]
            public IHttpActionResult Patch(int id, [FromBody] Student student) =>
                Ok(student);
        }
    }

    namespace V2
    {
        [ApiVersion("2.0")]
        [RoutePrefix("student")]
        public class StudentController : ApiController
        {
            [Route("{id}", Name = "GetStudentV2")]
            public IHttpActionResult Get(int id) =>
                Ok(new Student() { Id = id });

            [Route]
            public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] StudentV2 student)
            {
                student.Id = 42;
                var location = Link("GetStudentV2", new { id = student.Id });
                return Created(location, student);
            }

            [Route("{id}")]
            public IHttpActionResult Patch(int id, [FromBody] StudentV2 student) =>
                Ok(student);
        }
    }
}
```

I **strongly** advise against inheritance. It's possible, but is the wrong approach to the problem IMO. Neither APIs nor HTTP support *inheritance*. That is an implementation detail of the backing language, which is also somewhat of an impedance mismatch. A key problem is that you cannot *uninherit* a method and, hence, nor an API.

If you *really* insist on inheritance. Choose one of the following options:

- Base class with **only** `protected` members
- Move business logic out of the controllers
- Use extension methods or other collaborators to fulfill shared operations

For example, you *might* do something like this:

```cs
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    public abstract class StudentController<T> : ApiController
        where T: Student
    {
        protected virtual IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            // common implementation
        }

        protected virtual IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] T student)
        {
            // common implementation
        }

        protected virtual IHttpActionResult Patch(int id, [FromBody] Student student)
        {
            // common implementation
        }
    }

    namespace V1
    {
        [ApiVersion("1.0")]
        [RoutePrefix("student")]
        public class StudentController : StudentController<Student>
        {
            [Route("{id}", Name = "GetStudentV1")]
            public IHttpActionResult Get(int id) => base.Get(id);

            [Route]
            public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] Student student) =>
                base.Post(student);

            [Route("{id}")]
            public IHttpActionResult Patch(int id, [FromBody] Student student) =>
                base.Patch(student);
        }
    }

    namespace V2
    {
        [ApiVersion("2.0")]
        [RoutePrefix("student")]
        public class StudentController : StudentController<StudentV2>
        {
            [Route("{id}", Name = "GetStudentV2")]
            public IHttpActionResult Get(int id) => base.Get(id);

            [Route]
            public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] StudentV2 student) =>
                base.Post(student);

            [Route("{id}")]
            public IHttpActionResult Patch(int id, [FromBody] StudentV2 student) =>
                base.Patch(student);
        }
    }
}
```

There are other ways, but that is one example. If you define a sensible versioning policy (ex: *N-2* versions), then the amount of duplication is minimal. Inheritance will likely cause more problems than it solves.

When you version by media type, the default behavior uses the `v` media type parameter to indicate the API version. You can change name if you wish. Other forms of versioning by media type are possible (ex: `application/json+student.v1`, you'd need a custom **IApiVersionReader** as there is no *standard* format. In addition, you'll have to update the ASP.NET **MediaTypeFormatter** mappings in the configuration. The built-in media type mapping does not consider media type parameters (e.g. the `v` parameter has no impact).

The following table shows the mapping:

| Method | Header | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `GET` | `Accept` | `application/json;v=1.0` |
| `PUT` | `Content-Type` | `application/json;v=1.0` |
| `POST` | `Content-Type` | `application/json;v=1.0` |
| `PATCH` | `Content-Type` | `application/json;v=1.0` |
| `DELETE` | `Accept` or `Content-Type` | `application/json;v=1.0` |

`DELETE` is an outlier case as it doesn't require a media type in or out. `Content-Type` will always take precedence over `Accept` because it is required for the body. A `DELETE` API can be made API *version-neutral*, meaning will take any API version, including none at all. This may be useful if you want to allow `DELETE` without requiring a media type. Another alternative could be to use media type and query string versioning methods. This would allow specifying the API version in the query string for `DELETE` APIs.

Over the wire, it will look like:

#### Request

```
POST /student HTTP/2
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/json;v=2.0
Content-Length: 37

{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}
```

#### Response

```
HTTP/2 201 Created
Content-Type: application/json;v=2.0
Content-Length: 45
Location: http://localhost/student/42

{"id":42,"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your pasted code you could make *AbstractStudentController* generic.
Because those APIs that you declare abstract must be implemented in every API version, and you can define type with the generic. I hope I'm not missing something from your description, because Patch is missing from your implementation in StudentV2Controller, but is declared abstract. Do you wanted to derive StudentV2Controller from StudentV1Controller?

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseController : ApiController
{
    // common methods for all api
}

public abstract class AbstractStudentController<StudentType> : AbstractBaseController
{
    // common methods for Student related API'sample

    public abstract Post(StudentType student);
    public abstract Patch(StudentType student);
}

public class StudentV1Controller : AbstractStudentController<StudentV1>
{
    public override Post([FromBody]StudentV1 student) // student should be instance of StudentV1 from JSON
    {
        // To Do: Insert V1 Student
    }

    public override Patch([FromBody]StudentV1 student) // student should be instance of StudentV1 from JSON
    {
        // To Do: Patch V1 Student
    }
}

public class StudentV2Controller : AbstractStudentController<StudentV2>
{
    // 
    public override Post([FromBody]StudentV2 student) // student should be instance of StudentV2 from JSON
    {
        // To Do: Insert V2 Student
    }
}
```