# ASP.NET Core Web API : abstract class param binding

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, model-binding

I have a DTO which is an abstract class. When I am calling the Web API, I need to pass the child class. I followed this link [Binding abstract action parameters in WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306305/binding-abstract-action-parameters-in-webapi) but what I am not getting is where to put

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(
new PolymorphicProductConverter()
);
```

This code in my ASP.NET Core application.

Can anyone please help?

My models are like this

```
public abstract class HrBuildingComponentV1DTO
{
        public HrBuildingComponentV1DTO() { }

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public BuildingComponentType Type { get; set; }
        public int? Index { get; set; }
        public bool IsFilter { get; set; }
        public string SectionId { get; set; }

        public HrBuildingComponentV1DTO(HrBuildingComponentsV1 component)
        {
            Id = component.Id;
            Label = component.Label;
            Type = component.Type;
            Index = component.Index;
            IsFilter = component.IsFilter;
            SectionId = component.SectionId;
        }

         public abstract HrBuildingComponentsV1 ToModel();
}

public class HrTextBuildingComponentV1DTO : HrBuildingComponentV1DTO
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public HrTextBuildingComponentV1DTO() : base() { }

    public HrTextBuildingComponentV1DTO(HrTextBuildingComponentV1 model) : base(model)
    {
        Value = model.Value;
    }

    public override HrBuildingComponentsV1 ToModel()
    {
        return new HrTextBuildingComponentV1(this);
    }
}
```

Here is my custom converter

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;

namespace HumanRisks.API.Helpers
{
    public class PolymorphicHrBuildingComponentConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(HrBuildingComponentV1DTO);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, 
            object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
            HrBuildingComponentV1DTO product;
            var pt = obj["Type"];
            if (pt == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Missing productType", "productType");
            }

            BuildingComponentType productType = pt.Value<BuildingComponentType>();
            if (productType == BuildingComponentType.Text)
            {
                product = new HrTextBuildingComponentV1DTO();
            }
            else if (productType == BuildingComponentType.TextArea)
            {
                product = new HrTextAreaBuildingComponentV1DTO();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Unknown product type: " + productType);
            }

            serializer.Populate(obj.CreateReader(), product);
            return product;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create your own converter class inheriting from JsonConverter.

Comment: I have already done that but where do I put it so that it can be use? I mean where to put the code to tell the api to use my converter?

Comment: I have added code for my custom converter as well

Comment: If you wan to know how to let the auto model binding to use custom jsonconverter, I suggest you could add it via addcontroller method like this:        services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new PolymorphicHrBuildingComponentConverter ());
        });

Comment: I was using NewtonSoft and that was having issue with JsonSoft. Was able to fix it like this             services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new PolymorphicDisplayLogicConverter());
                options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new PolymorphicHrBuildingComponentConverter());
            });